# Proof of a star domain

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

For part (a) I'm confused as to how to prove the set is a star domain. I know that a possible star centre is $z_0=0$. I think it involves letting z be a member of $U_1$ therefore $|\operatorname{Re}(z)|<1$ and $|\operatorname{Im}(z)|<1,$ and so then you claim the line segment [$z_0$,z] lies in $U_1$.

Then any point $w$ in [$z_0$,z] takes the form $w=(1-t)z_0+tz$ with $0\le t\le1$. Although I'm not sure how to adapt this equation as it was for the case $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$ but that is a straight line and for this case it is a square with corners (1,1),(1,-1),(-1,-1),(-1,1).

Answer (score 1):

(a) Any convex set is trivially a star domain.

(c) $0$ is a star centre. Indeed, let $x=\operatorname{Re}z$,  $y=\operatorname{Im}z$. The open set $\mathcal U_3$ is defined by the condition $\;|xy|<1$ and a  point between the origin and the point with affix $z$ has coordinates $(tx,ty)$  for some $t\in[0,1]$. So $\; |tx\mkern2mu ty|=t^2|xy|< 1 $.

(b)  $D'$ is not a star domain because there are pairs of points of D'such that the line segment joining them is not entirely contained in D' (take two points on a diameter of the unit circle).

Comment: D' is a punctured disk or neighborhood.

Comment: for (c) is the proof similar to that of (a) involving t? I understand your hint but i'm not sure about the geometric shape.

Comment: The same except one is a star domain and the other is not. The proof consists in checking whether the definition of a star domain is satisfied or finding a counter-example. As to the shapes, I don't see any problem:  $U_1$ is the (open) unit square centred at origin, $U_2$ is the unit punctured disk and $U_3$ is the open domain in $\mathbf R^2$ between the two branches of the hyperbola $y=1/x$.

Comment: Can you give a detailed proof of (c) please ?

Comment: @niloderoock: I've added a proof. Is it clear enough?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, it is clear enough. Sorry for answering late.

Comment: @niloderoock:  no worry.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Geometrically speaking this is the interior of a square. We can show this is a star domain with respect for instance to $z_0=0$. To do that, let $z=x+yi$ be in $U_1$, so that $|x|<1$ and $|y|<1$. We need to show that 
$$tz+(1-t)z_0=tz\in U_1$$ for every $t\in [0,1]$. But this is obvious since
$$|Re(tz)|=|tx|=|t|\,|x|<1$$
since $|t|\leq 1$ and $|x|<1$. Similarly $|Im(tz)|<1$ and hence $tz\in U_1$.

Comment: For part (c) i'm not sure how to prove that this is a star domain, i can't quite grasp the geometric shape of the set, would it be geometrically a diamond shape? Would it be a similar method to part (a) using t?

Comment: The condition in (c) can be rewritten as $x=0$ or $|y|<1/|x|$, that is $-1/x<|y|<1/x$. The domain (c) is therefore sandwiched between the hyperboles of equations $y=1/x$ and $y=-1/x$, with the addition of the y-axis: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=draw+%7Cxy%7C%3C1,+-5%3Cx%3C5,+-5%3Cy%3C5

Comment: If $z\in U_3$ we need to show that $tz\in U_3$ as well if $t\in ]0,1]$ (obvious if $t=0$). This is trivial if $z$ lies on the y-axis. Otherwise, we may assume by symmetry that $z=x+yi$ where $x>0$, $0<y<1/x$. Then $tz=(tx)+(ty)i$ so that $tx>0$ and $0<ty<t/x\leq 1/(tx)$ since $t\leq 1/t$ whenever $t\in ]0,1]$. This shows that $tz\in U_3$.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand how the last line proves that it is a star domain, why does showing $ty$ is between 0 and $\frac{1}{tx}$ show that $|Re(z)Im(z)|\lt1$?

Comment: We rather want to show that $tz\in U_3$. Since $0<ty<\dfrac{1}{tx}$ we have $|Re(tz)Im(tz)|=|(tx)(ty)|<1$.